# SMTP Setting in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, smtp

I'm using cakephp for new project. I need to fetch the SMTP setting from database table for sending emails. is that any possible way. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The docs says:

> CakeEmail will create an instance of the EmailConfig class to access the config. If you have dynamic data to put in the configs, you can use the constructor to do that:

So you could do something like this:

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $dynamic;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->dynamic = ClassRegistry::init('MailConfig')->getConfig();
    }
}
```

Where MailConfig is a Model and getConfig() is a function in that model that loads the configuration from the database and return it in a valid CakeEmail configuration format.

Later you can use the dynamic configuration as follow:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('dynamic');
```

link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html